# How to use closest() in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, closest

I am trying to get value of a text box by using closest().
My form contains dynamically created table with one text box and button in each row . I want to show the value of text box in button click event. 
Table format is given below

```
<table id="dataarea" class="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>jaison<td>
            <td class="amountclm">
                <input id="txtamt" class="amtcls" type="text" value="100">
            </td>
            <td>
                <button id="schedule" class="schbtn btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="UpdateSchedule()">Confirm</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>ARUN<td>
            <td class="amountclm">
                <input id="txtamt" class="amtcls" type="text" value="500">
            </td>
            <td>
                <button id="schedule" class="schbtn btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="UpdateSchedule()">Confirm</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have written one javascript code (given below) . when the code will execute, it return a null value.

Function

```
function UpdateSchedule() {
    var amt2 = $(this).closest('td.amountclm').find('.amtcls').val();
    alert( amt2); 
}
```

Please let me know why am not getting the null value.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery `.closest()` goes up from the current element until it finds what you give it to find. jQuery `.find()` goes down until it finds what you give it to find.

This does the trick:

http://jsfiddle.net/6T3ET/

Answer (score 0):

`id` must be unique, you need to use class instead:

```
<button class="schedule schbtn btn btn-primary" type="button">
<input class="amtcls txtamt" type="text" value="500">
```

an use `.click()` instead of inline `onClick` handler since you're using jQuery. So you can do:

```
$('.schedule').click(function() {
    var amt2 = $(this).closest('td').prev('td.amountclm').find('.amtcls').val();
    alert( amt2); 
});
```

Please note that the `.amountclm` input is the child of a `td` whose is the immediate previous sibling of parent `td` of your clicked `.schedule`  button.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

replace 'this' with  the 'schedule_' class attribute

```
function UpdateSchedule() {

    var amt2 = $(".schedule_").closest('td.amountclm').find('.amtcls').val();
    alert( amt2); 
 }
```

HTML :

```
<table id="dataarea" class="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>jaison<td>
            <td class="amountclm">
                <input id="txtamt" class="amtcls" type="text" value="100">
            </td>
            <td>
                <button id="schedule" class="schbtn btn btn-primary schedule_" type="button" onclick="UpdateSchedule()">Confirm</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>ARUN<td>
            <td class="amountclm">
                <input id="txtamt" class="amtcls" type="text" value="500">
            </td>
            <td>
                <button id="schedule" class="schbtn btn btn-primary schedule_" type="button" onclick="UpdateSchedule()">Confirm</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

or try with Jquery as

```
$(document).on('click', '.schedule_',function(){

   var amt2 = $(this).closest('td.amountclm').find('.amtcls').val();
        alert( amt2); 
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **`.parent()`** and **`.prev()`** in jquery for this contradiction

```
$(".schbtn").click(function() {

    var amt2 = $(this).parent().prev("td.amountclm").find('.amtcls').val();
    alert( amt2); 
});
```

[***Fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/WHz6U/)

Answer (score 0):

First of all .closest() is not plain JavaScript. It's a function from jQuery.

http://api.jquery.com/closest/

and it traverses up in the element hierachy. And td.amountclm is not in the element hierachy of the button#schedule.

Therefore .closest wont find it.